# How to get rid off dependency between Model Attributes and Table Column Names in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I know how to use BeanPropertyRowMapper and RowMapper as well.

But if I use BeanPropertyRowMapper,
 i.e.

```
BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyClass> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyClass>(MyClass.class);
```

MyClass attributes becomes tightly coupled with tables column names and if I use RowMapper still MyClass attributes becomes tightly coupled and I have to write few more lines of code populate MyClass attribute with first GET and then SET operation extra.

Is there any way we can get rid of this dependency. Even after Table Columns names are changed, MyClass attributes should be populated as before and I do not need to change my code.

Comment: Is this a good alternative http://modelmapper.org/ ???

Answer (score 0):

The Dozer mapping tool sounds like a good fit for what you're trying to do, and it's pretty simple to use. You'd still have to change *something* when changing column names, but it should be pretty easy. Check this out: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/